# Logstash not ingesting content into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have installed elasticsearch-8.2.3 logstash-8.2.3 and kibana-8.2.3  I have configure the logstash conf file to ingest content into elasticsearch, logstash run without any error but it is not ingesting the content.

Below is the conf file:

```
  input {
  #stdin {type => "stdin-type" }
  file
  {
    path => "D:/logstash-8.2.3/inspec/*.*"
    type => "file"
    start_position=>"beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
    ignore_older => 0
  }
}
filter {
    csv
    {
        columns =>
                    [
                      "itemid","itemtitle","rlabel","ayear","rid","rsid","anotatedby","anotatetime","antype","astate","broaderlevel3","broaderlevel2","broaderlevel1","categorylabel","toppreferedlabel"
                    ]
        separator => ","
        remove_field => ["type","host"]
        }
   
    
    mutate 
    {
    split => { "antype" => ";" }
    split => { "broaderlevel3" => ";" }
    split => { "broaderlevel2" => ";" }
    split => { "broaderlevel1" => ";" }
    split => { "categorylabel" => ";" }
    split => { "toppreferedlabel" => ";" }
    
    
    }
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch
   {
        hosts => ["localhost"]
        
        index => "iet-tv"
   }
}
```

I don't get any error message while running logstash but content not getting ingested into Elasticsearch.

Below is the log:

```
    [2022-06-29T14:03:03,579][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: D:\logstash-8.2.3\config\log4j2.properties
[2022-06-29T14:03:03,595][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] The use of JAVA_HOME has been deprecated. Logstash 8.0 and later ignores JAVA_HOME and uses the bundled JDK. Running Logstash with the bundled JDK is recommended. The bundled JDK has been verified to work with each specific version of Logstash, and generally provides best performance and reliability. If you have compelling reasons for using your own JDK (organizational-specific compliance requirements, for example), you can configure LS_JAVA_HOME to use that version instead.
[2022-06-29T14:03:03,598][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"8.2.3", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.20.1 (2.5.8) 2021-11-30 2a2962fbd1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.15+10 on 11.0.15+10 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2022-06-29T14:03:03,600][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -Djruby.jit.threshold=0, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED]
[2022-06-29T14:03:03,736][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2022-06-29T14:03:11,340][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
[2022-06-29T14:03:12,628][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 153 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 120 keys and 395 values 
[2022-06-29T14:03:15,580][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline `main` is configured with `pipeline.ecs_compatibility: v8` setting. All plugins in this pipeline will default to `ecs_compatibility => v8` unless explicitly configured otherwise.
[2022-06-29T14:03:15,662][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost"]}
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,210][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,532][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,549][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch version determined (8.2.3) {:es_version=>8}
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,553][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>8}
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,627][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,627][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,632][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch Output configured with `ecs_compatibility => v8`, which resolved to an UNRELEASED preview of version 8.0.0 of the Elastic Common Schema. Once ECS v8 and an updated release of this plugin are publicly available, you will need to update this plugin to resolve this warning.
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,652][INFO ][logstash.filters.csv     ][main] ECS compatibility is enabled but `target` option was not specified. This may cause fields to be set at the top-level of the event where they are likely to clash with the Elastic Common Schema. It is recommended to set the `target` option to avoid potential schema conflicts (if your data is ECS compliant or non-conflicting, feel free to ignore this message)
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,694][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>8, :ecs_compatibility=>:v8}
[2022-06-29T14:03:16,762][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["D:/logstash-8.2.3/conf/inspec.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x48e38277 run>"}
[2022-06-29T14:03:18,017][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.25}
[2022-06-29T14:03:18,102][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2022-06-29T14:03:18,171][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][2c845ee5978dc5ed1bf8d0f617965d2013df9d31461210f0e7c2b799e02f6bb8] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2022-06-29T14:03:18,220][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks

Dharmendra Kumar Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In filebeat, `ignore_older => 0` turns off age-based filtering. In a logstash file input it tells the filter to ignore any file more than zero seconds old, and since the file input sleeps between its periodic polls for new files, that can mean it ignores all files, even if they are being updated.

Comment: Many Thanks Badger i removed ignore_older => 0 and it worked .. Thanks again

Comment: I am new to Logstash and I am facing the same issue. Can you please tell me where to add this line in Logstash conf file?

Comment: You don't add it, you remove it if it is already present.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Windows 10, Logstash 8.1.0), the file path with back-slashes ( C:\path\to\csv\etc.CSV ) caused the same issue, changing back-slashes to forward-slashes fixed the problem.

Here is a working logstash config:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/path/to/csv/file.csv"
        type => "file"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "NUL"
    }
}
filter {
  csv {
    columns => 
        [
          "WID","LID","IID","Product","QTY","TID"
        ]
    separator => ","
  }
  mutate {        
        rename => { 
            "WID" => "w_id"
            "LID" => "l_id"
            "IID" => "i_id"
            "Product" => "product"
            "QTY" => "quantity" 
        }
        convert => {
            "w_id" => "integer"
            "l_id" => "integer"
            "i_id" => "integer"
            "quantity" => "float"
        }
        remove_field => [
            "@timestamp", 
            "@version", 
            "host",
            "message", 
            "type",
            "path", 
            "event",
            "log",
            "TID"
        ]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    action => "index"
    hosts => ["https://127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "product_inline"
  }
  stdout { }
}
```